# Installing Plastic SCM on Ubuntu

Tags: apt

I just wanted to install Plastic SCM on my Ubuntu 21.10.
Already tried to fix broken and missing packages.

```
Package lists are read... Done
Dependency tree is built... Done
Status information is read... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This can mean that
that you have requested an impossible situation or, if you are using the
unstable distribution, that some required packages have not been built yet or that
have not been built or have not left Incoming yet.
The following information may help you resolve the situation:

The following packages have unfulfilled dependencies:
 plasticscm-gnome-sharp-mono4 : Depends on: libgnome2-0 (>= 2.17.3) but is not installable.
                                Depends on: libgnomeui-0 but is not installable
E: Problems can't be fixed, you have held back broken packages.
```

Comment: Hello. Have you tried to install the 2 missing apps?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install `plasticscm-gnome-sharp-mono4` on any version of Ubuntu newer than 18.04, as the packages the software depends on was deprecated over four years ago.

As such, you have a few options:

1. Install the software on Ubuntu 18.04
2. [Download](https://www.plasticscm.com/download) and use the newer, better maintained versions of PlasticSCM
3. [Find a Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=PlasticSCM) with the version you want to run

**Warning:** *Do not follow [these instructions](https://plasticscmsupport.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013103159-How-to-Install-Plastic-GUI-in-Ubuntu-19-10-and-later-) from PlasticSCM Support on a modern version of Ubuntu. You will break your system.*